# How to get list of ID's for all the projects in a group on Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I am a beginner with GitLab and GitLab api so there is alot of basic knowledge of that i might be missing.
I have a synology server where i want to make backups of the GitLab projects. Due to network limitations there is no GitLab Installation on Synology therefore i want to back-up the gitlab projects in this way.

Idea: Using GitLab api i want to extract a list of GitLab project ID's, loop through these id's and export and download the project(s) to a location on Synology.

The main problem i am having right now is getting all the Project ID's in a list that i can loop through or any similar data structure.

Does any of you have any idea about how i could accomplish this?

At the moment i am trying out getting all the projects owned using the following api call:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: MyToken" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects?owned=true"
```

At the moment i am just getting an empty pair of square brackets as a result. I am not sure why that is yet as i am kind of figuring things out as i go.

Is it possible to parse the information about the projects owned to extract only the project ID's?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `--header 'Accept: application/json'` to your curl command.

Answer (score 0):

Try This instead:

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: MyToken" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects"
```